# How do I fetch on an update to a url containing JSON?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

I am running a couple of arduino mini's who send JSON data to a url-path on my website. Currently I have managed to fetch the data just fine, but would like to fetch upon JSON changes to the url, instead of fetching every x seconds.

Code for the fetch part:

```
async function getMini4 () {
  let response = await fetch('/api/sensor/mini4')
  let data = await response.json()
  return data
}
```

And the Express that posts the formatted json:

```
app.get('/api/sensor/mini1', (req, resp, next) => {
  resp.send(gyroData1)
})

app.post('/api/sensor/mini1', (req, resp, next) => {
  gyroData1 = req.body
  resp.send()
})
```

The fetch works just fine, but I can't seem to find anything on fetching when the url changes.

Comment: Do you mean when the _content_ of the URL changes? If so, how is the client supposed to know it has changed without pulling it down and comparing with the last version?

Comment: Yes might have worded that incorrectly. Since my intention is to use it as a proof of concept, and not something suistainable for more users than one. Was wondering if you could send an update/message to the client, that new data is now available and can be fetched.

Comment: You might have another URL that had a lightweight message, such as a version number, that would make the comparison easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) ? This protocol allow you to push update from the server to the client and it seems to exactly fit your need.